# Closures in Ruby with Module

Tags: ruby

I am a bit puzzled on why this piece of code does not work:

```
def create(type)
  Module.new do
    def foo
      type
    end
  end
end
```

When calling `foo` on the returned Module, `type` is not defined.
Am I supposed to use a Proc or a lambda to capture the scope within the create method?

(I probably have done too much JavaScript recently)

tl;dr
How can I create Module at runtime with methods that use variables available at the time of creation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`type` is a local variable. Well, technically, it is a parameter, but parameters behave identically to local variables.

Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in, that's why they are called "local" variables: `type` is defined inside the `create` method, it is not defined inside the `foo` method.

There are 4 local variables scopes in Ruby:

- script
- module / class definition
- method definition
- block

Of these four, only block scopes nest, the others create new scopes. So, if you want to use variables from an outer scope, you *must* use a block.

Thankfully, there is a method to define a method that takes a block, and it is aptly named [`Module#define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-define_method):

```
def create(type)
  Module.new do
    define_method(:foo) do
      type
    end
  end
end
```

By the way: the assignment to `m` was unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution but mostly for the explanation! I'll remember only blocks capture their outer scope ;)